# C# / Visual Studio issue with date format

Tags: c#

My application provides an export function to create a text file that can be imported to another software. The export file, has to look exactly like the other software has specified, in terms of formatting etc.

There is a date field that has to be in the format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss".

The following code is used to write the line containing the date:

```
            txt += "       Started at: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")+"\n";
```

Now when i look at the created text file, the date is in the wrong format, its formatted as following:

```
yyyy.mm.dd HH:mm:ss
```

I tried to swap out some characters to see if its a general issue, but it seems related to `/`, when i replace the `/` by `_` or `-` it works as expected, even if only switch one of the three `/`, only the `/` gets wrongly converted into a point.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: It is issue of culture, try this out 

  var cult = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
  var txt = "       Started at: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", cult) + "\n";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` in custom datetime formatting refers to the "current system date separator", not the literal `/`.

To use a literal `/`, append it in quotes or double quotes, e.g:

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Here's the documentation about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator

PS: notice the same happens with `:` for time

Answer (score 0):

Just like "mm" is replace by the month, the "/" is replaced by the "date specifier".
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator